# Couldn't start mysql even when there is no services using port 3306

Tags: xampp, mariadb

I have an issue with mysql XAMPP. When I try to start mysql, it failed and here's the error message that I copied from mysql_error.log.

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-01-25 19:44:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-01-25 19:44:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-01-25 19:44:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-01-25 19:44:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-01-25 19:44:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-01-25 19:44:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-01-25 19:44:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-01-25 19:44:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: 1 out of 1 rollback segments are active.
2020-01-25 19:44:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-01-25 19:44:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-01-25 19:44:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-01-25 19:44:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.8 started; log sequence number 34888; transaction id 7
2020-01-25 19:44:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 3 !!!
2020-01-25 19:44:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-01-25 19:44:16 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-01-25 19:44:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200125 19:44:16
2020-01-25 19:44:16 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

The following solutions I have tried:

1. Delete ibdata1 in data folder.
2. Added `innodb_force_recovery = 3` below mysqld in my.ini

When I try to start MySql module in XAMPP Control Panel. I received the following error message.

> [mysql] Status change detected: stopped [mysql] Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. [mysql] This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, [mysql] improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method. [mysql] Press the Logs button to view error logs and check [mysql] the Windows Event Viewer for more clues [mysql] If you need more help, copy and post this [mysql] entire log window on the forums

Here is what I got from Event Viewer:

> Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Incorrect file format 'roles_mapping'

Comment: That looks like a successful restart log? What makes you think mariaDB has not started

Comment: Actually that is a mariaDB table, it can be found in the `\data\mysql` folder, so this is serious

Comment: Does the user that is running the service actually have read write access to the tables

Comment: Why did you delete the ibdata1 file? To have an unusable data dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting ibdata1 has the effect of throwing away all your data.  I hope that either you are just starting, or you have a backup.

> Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M

That is terribly tiny.  Change it in my.cnf to, say, 200M.

Comment: @RayCoder - It's been most of a year, and you did not ask the question.  If you are "min", provide more info.  If you are a different person, start a separate question with _your_ specifics.  In either case, dba.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -2):

i had the same problem when i installed the xampp in E drive.Installing in to C solved the problem for me