# Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. on xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

I face the following error in xampp.

```
    InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-12-07 14:49:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-12-07 14:49:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-12-07 14:49:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-12-07 14:49:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-12-07 14:49:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-12-07 14:49:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-12-07 14:49:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-12-07 14:49:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-12-07 14:49:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-12-07 14:49:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-12-07 14:49:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-12-07 14:49:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-12-07 14:49:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.10 started; log sequence number 280252366; transaction id 231680
2020-12-07 14:49:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-12-07 14:49:27 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-12-07 14:49:27 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-12-07 14:49:27 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 201207 14:49:27
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-12-07 14:50:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-12-07 14:50:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-12-07 14:50:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-12-07 14:50:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-12-07 14:50:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-12-07 14:50:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-12-07 14:50:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-12-07 14:50:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-12-07 14:50:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-12-07 14:50:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-12-07 14:50:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-12-07 14:50:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-12-07 14:50:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.10 started; log sequence number 280252375; transaction id 231680
2020-12-07 14:50:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-12-07 14:50:05 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-12-07 14:50:05 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-12-07 14:50:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 201207 14:50:05
```

I try changing the port from 3306 to 3308 then I change it to 3307. Also, I try upgrading the size from 2MB to 200MB. Also I try this methods: [Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. on xampp-control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62749931/error-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly-on-xampp-control) [Couldn't start mysql even when there is no services using port 3306](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59908839/couldnt-start-mysql-even-when-there-is-no-services-using-port-3306)

If you have any information regarding this problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and testing different methods, I found the answer, I just run `setup_xampp.bat` in xampp directory, and after that, the program starts working.